# How to filter out rows that start with a certain value in R?

Tags: r, subset

I have a data set like the one below

| ID | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 042 | 10 |
| 2 | 353 | 13 |
| 3 | 403 | 03 |
| 4 | 642 | 22 |

I want to filter out only the rows that have a value in col1 that start with 4. This includes row1 that has 04, but does not include row 4. Col1 is a character column.

The final data set should look like this.

| ID | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 353 | 13 |
| 4 | 642 | 22 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(substring(as.numeric(col1),1,1) != "4")

  ID col1 col2
1  2  353   13
2  4  642   22
```

Answer (score 1):

We can combine `str_detect` with `filter` using the regex `'^0+4|^4'` that indicates starts with 0 one or more times followed by a 4 or starts with 4.

code:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_table("ID    col1    col2
1   042 10
2   353 13
3   403 03
4   642 22")


df %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(col1, '^0+4|^4'))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>      ID col1  col2 
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     2 353   13   
#> 2     4 642   22
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>